# Getting different tkinter coordinates for same mouse position with different event bindings

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates

I'm developing a tkinter application that lets you click-and-drag around a map and zoom in and out with the scroll wheel. The UI also has a wider section below the main map, which causes the application to be wider than just the `Canvas` object for the map.

However, I'm getting different coordinates for the location of click-and-drag events and scroll wheel events: the former are coordinates within the canvas, just like I'd expect, whereas the latter have the x-coordinate increased by the amount of padding added by the wider object on the bottom.

Here's a minimal working example (using all motion instead of just click-and-drag):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk


class MainCanvas(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, tk_parent):
        super().__init__(tk_parent, height=200, width=200, bg="green")
        self.pack()
        self.bind("<Motion>",     self.print_move)
        self.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.print_scroll)  # For Mac
        self.bind("<Button-4>",   self.print_scroll)  # For Linux
        self.bind("<Button-5>",   self.print_scroll)  # For Linux

    def print_coords(self, name, event):
        print("{}: x: ({}, {}), y: ({}, {})".format(
            name,
            event.x, int(self.canvasx(event.x)),
            event.y, int(self.canvasy(event.y))))

    def print_move(self, event):
        self.print_coords("moving", event)

    def print_scroll(self, event):
        self.print_coords("scroll", event)


class Bottom(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self, tk_parent):
        super().__init__(tk_parent, height=5, width=500, bg="red")
        self.pack()


class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, tk_parent):
        super().__init__(tk_parent)
        self.pack()
        self.main = MainCanvas(self)
        self.bottom = Bottom(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    gui = GUI(root)

    # Make an easy way to exit
    for char in "wWqQ":
        root.bind("<Control-{}>".format(char), lambda _: root.destroy())

    root.mainloop()
```

and some example output:

```
moving: x: (14, 14), y: (117, 117)
moving: x: (14, 14), y: (118, 118)
scroll: x: (164, 164), y: (118, 118)
scroll: x: (164, 164), y: (118, 118)
moving: x: (14, 14), y: (117, 117)
moving: x: (14, 14), y: (116, 116)
moving: x: (15, 15), y: (116, 116)
moving: x: (15, 15), y: (115, 115)
moving: x: (15, 15), y: (114, 114)
moving: x: (16, 16), y: (114, 114)
scroll: x: (166, 166), y: (114, 114)
scroll: x: (166, 166), y: (114, 114)
moving: x: (15, 15), y: (114, 114)
moving: x: (14, 14), y: (114, 114)
moving: x: (14, 14), y: (113, 113)
moving: x: (13, 13), y: (113, 113)
scroll: x: (163, 163), y: (113, 113)
scroll: x: (163, 163), y: (113, 113)
moving: x: (13, 13), y: (112, 112)
moving: x: (13, 13), y: (111, 111)
moving: x: (13, 13), y: (110, 110)
```

I would like a way to  have the same coordinate system for both motion and scrolling events, but as you can see, the scroll events are shifted 150 pixels to the right, corresponding to the 150 pixels of padding on the left due to the red canvas at the bottom. Using the `.canvasx` and `.canvasy` functions to move the event into the canvas' coordinate system does not help.

Any ideas how to work around this? I don't want to subtract a constant 150 pixels from the scroll event coordinates because the overall window is resizable, so the amount of padding might be much larger.

I'm using Python 3.7.2 and tkinter version 8.6 on a Mac (Mojave), though my application has the same behavior on Ubuntu with several versions of Python and tkinter. (Disclaimer: I haven't tried the MWE on Ubuntu, but I expect it to work the same.)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: In Archlinux with python 3.7.1 and tk 8.6.9 I cannot reproduce the issue with the MCVE: I get the exact same x coordinates for moving and scrolling (the ones without the right shift).